# Deserialize a complex dynamic JSON string

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, deserialization, complextype

What if the object to deserialize looked like this (where the keys Ioc, Name, id and timestamp are static, and the fields key is dynamic - meaning that it may contain a variable amount of items)???

```
{
   "moduleinstances": [
     {
        "Ioc": "ioc1", 
        "Name": "name1", 
        "fields": {
            "PV_PREFIX": "PIPE", 
            "TIMEOUT": "1"
        }, 
        "id": 25, 
        "timestamp": "/Date(1393518678000)/"
     }
    ]
}
```

How to deserialize this kind of strings?

Comment: Try [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Try the site mentioned by L.B and use Json.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is to keep your deserialized JSON in the most general form possible:

```
Dictionary<string, object> theData= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

Dictionary<string, object> fieldsNode = (Dictionary<string, object>)theData["fields"];

string pv_prefix = (string)fieldsNode["PV_PREFIX"];
string timeout = (string)fieldsNode["TIMEOUT"];
```

The call to `Deserialize()` creates a tree of `Dictionary<string, object>` that you can traverse at will.